# Model accuracy reduction in .tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently developing some model optimization using TensorFlow by trying different features (quantization, weight pruning...) in some of my company models.
My problem comes when I convert an h5 model to .tflite without any type of special optimization with the following code:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

The model (MobileNet v2) size went from **18.5 MB to 8.9 MB** and accuracy from **99.48% to 98.51%**
I can't explain this change that is also happening in other models, for example, this ResNet50:
**94.9MB to 94MB** and **98.51% to 94.51%**.

Why is the conversion to .tflite reducing weight and accuracy without any type of extra optimization?

Comment: Hi! Model Optimization is necessary to improve the accuracy of Tflite model as it does compress the model and  resize model parameters  during conversion so that it can run in a mobile/edge device friendly environment . You can refer to the document below to improve accuracy.  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Optimize   https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization